# Computing the inverse of a Cholesky decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, matrix-inverse

I have chol(A) and I would like chol(A^-1). One way to do this is to construct the inverse positive definite symmetric matrix and then take its Cholesky decomposition (with Dpotri and Dpotrf for example). Is that the only way or can the process be short-circuited?

Answer (score 2):

The inverse of a lower triangular matrix with nonzero diagonal elements is easy to construct, and is also lower triangular.  If $A = L L'$, then $A^{-1} = (L^{-1})' L^{-1}$.  However, this is (upper triangular) (lower triangular) and we want (lower triangular) (upper triangular).  Let $J$ be the $n \times n$ antidiagonal matrix with $J_{ij} = 1$ for $i+j=n+1$, $0$ otherwise.  This has the property that $J^2 = I$, and $JLJ$ is  upper triangular iff $L$ is
lower triangular.  If the Cholesky decomposition of $JAJ$ is $JAJ = \tilde{L} \tilde{L}'$, then $A^{-1} = (J \tilde{L}^{-1}J)'(J \tilde{L}^{-1} J)$ 
is the Cholesky decomposition of $A^{-1}$.

Comment: That's close, except I have the Cholesky decomposition of A, not of J*A*J. Using the method you propose on the factorization of A gives me the factorization of J A^-1 J, not the factorization of A^-1 itself.

Comment: That's the best I have to offer.  The map from the Cholesky decomposition of $A$ to that of $A^{-1}$ does not appear to be simple.

Comment: Okay, that's what I thought. Thanks!

Comment: BTW, finding the map between the two is equivalent to finding a map from coefficients of an optimal left-to-right linear autoregressive model to coefficients of an optimal right-to-left one https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4493069/998